# Double backslash on last line of matrix

Tags: matrices

Is `\\` necessary on the final line of environments like `matrix`, `align`, and `gather`? For example, with `amsmath`,

```
\[\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 1\\
    2 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}\]
```

and

```
\[\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 1\\
    2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\]
```

seem to produce the same output. But are they really the same? Is one preferable to the other, or is it a matter of taste? From my understanding, `\\` in one of these environments is used to separate lines, and there's nothing else to separate the final line from, so it's not necessary.

Comment: If it produces the same output, I guess there's no difference.

Comment: I think there's no rule for this. I think it depends on the implementation of the environment. With `align`, for instance, you get an undesired line if you add the ``\\`` at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference at all for `bmatrix`. There *is* for `align`.

Any `array` or `tabular` allows a trailing `\\`; it is obviously mandatory if `\hline` is needed at the bottom, but otherwise omitting it is safe.

Since `Xmatrix` (where `X` stands for noting, `p`, `b`, `B`, `v` or `V`) is `array` in disguise, the same applies. Also `cases` falls in this class.

It's very different with `align`, `alignat`, `xalignat`, `flalign` and `gather` (or `*`-forms thereof), where a trailing `\\` would produce a new empty row (with the equation number in the case of no `*`), so it must be avoided.

As a habit, I tend to avoid the trailing `\\` in `Xmatrix`, just for symmetry with the alignment environments mentioned above.